# initiate POST method in jQuery without involving any input variables

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql, ajax

I am new to jQuery and PHP. This might be a trivial question or not.
Normally jQuery handles form input, post it to PHP, and then let PHP passes it to a database.
In my case, I have the current user's geographic location and I compare the user's geographic location against the destination's geographic location in JavaScript. If those two locations are close which means the user is arrived at the destination, record in the database by inserting the destination's Identifier (let's just say Id =1 to keep it simple) for the current user under the Place_Id filed in database. The table in the database only has two columns (userId and placeId).
I wonder how to achieve by jQuery and PHP.

Here is the JavaScript code  for geographic locations comparison. 
I need help on the function postIt() to initiate PHP using jQuery and the associate PHP.

```
  <script type="text/javascript" ,  
  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
  <script>
  var lat;
  var long;

  window.onload=function(){
  getLocation();
  }


  function getLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
  watchId = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(showPosition, locationError,
  {maximumAge:0, timeout:10000, enableHighAccuracy:true});
  } 
  else {
  alert("Browser doesn't support Geolocation. Visit http://caniuse.com to 
  discover browser support for the Geolocation API.");
     }
   }


  function locationError(error) {} // error function here


  function showPosition(position) {
  x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude +
  "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
  lat = position.coords.latitude;
  long = position.coords.longitude;

  comparePosition();
  }


  function comparePosition()
  {
       var userCurrentLat = lat;
       var userCurrentLong = long;
       var Dest1_Lat = 38.00;     //this is just for demo
       var Dest1_Long = -72.00;   //this is just for demo
  if (userCurrentLat == Dest1_Lat 
  &&  userCurrentLong == Dest1_Long)//just a simplified way of comparison 
  {
    postIt();

  }}

  function postIt()
  { $.post ('insertDest1.php', {current_user_id, //pseudo jQuery code here
  destinationId(1)}, callback function() )      //where I need help
    }
 </script>
```

PHP (insertDest1.php)

```
 <?php
 include ('mysqli_connect.php');
 $query = "INSERT INTO user (userId,placeId) VALUES 
    ('current_user_id' , '1')";     
 $result = @mysqli_query ($dbc, $query); // Run the query.
 if ($result) { // If it ran OK.

 // Print a message.
 echo '<h1 id="mainhead">Success!</h1>';
 }

 else { // If it did not run OK.
 echo '<h1 id="mainhead">Error</h1>';
 }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use $.ajax for more configuration options:

```
function postIt()
{ 
    $.ajax({
        url: 'insertDest1.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data:{
            userId: 'current_user_id', // replace with actual user id
            placeId: 'the_place_id' // replace with actual place id 
        },
        success: function(serverResponse) {
            // handle output from server here ('Success!' or 'Error' from PHP script)
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            // handle any network/server errors here
            console.log("Status: " + textStatus); 
            console.log("Error: " + errorThrown); 
        }
    });
}
```

Setup PHP file to handle POST data from AJAX

```
<?php
    include ('mysqli_connect.php');

    # Always sanitize input from $_POST variable to prevent SQL injection
    $userId = $dbc->escape_string($_POST['userId']); // current_user_id
    $placeId = $dbc->escape_string($_POST['placeId']); // the_place_id

    $query = "INSERT INTO user (userId, placeId) VALUES ('".$userId."' , '".$placeId."')";     
    $result = @mysqli_query ($dbc, $query); // Run the query.

    if ($result) { // If it ran OK.
        // Print a message.
        echo '<h1 id="mainhead">Success!</h1>';
    }
    else { // If it did not run OK.
        // Print error.
        echo '<h1 id="mainhead">Error</h1>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thank you Kevin HR! Your code worked very well for me.